# Is Common Lisp static or dynamically typed? If both how is it done?

Tags: dynamic, types, static, lisp, common-lisp

I m doing a paper on python vs lisp in functional programming. I was seeing the typing system in Common Lisp. I have read that it is dynamic, lexical, strong. But  my professor says it is static...can anyone clear this for me? its maddening!

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you would google it you will find tutorials and articles that can explain you about your question in details than what we can do it here. Also as a new member please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks!

Comment: What have you read about Common Lisp? Did you read the [Common Lisp HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/index.htm)? Notice the [`type`declaration](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/d_type.htm). Did you try to play with some CL implementation, such as [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/)? SBCL is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), so you can (and probably should) study some of its source code (written in Common Lisp) which is a good example of CL code.

Comment: Actually, CL has both static and dynamic typing aspects. That it why it is fascinating.

Comment: How is this too broad? Dynamic, period.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the seminal paper on types by Luca Cardelli and Peter Wegner: On understanding types, data abstraction, and polymorphism, ACM Computing Surveys, 17(4):471-522, 1985,

> Programming languages in which the type of every expression can be determined by static program analysis are said to be statically typed.

This is not true for Common Lisp. Consider, for instance, the following, legal, function definition:

```
(defun f(g x)
  (funcall g x))
```

The type of the expression `(funcall g x)` inside the body of the function cannot be inferred or determined statically in any way.

In Common Lisp however you can, if you want, specify the types of the parameters of a function. For instance:

```
(defun f (g x)
  (declare (type integer x)
           (type (function (integer) float) g))
  (funcall g x))
```

and in this case the compiler can infer that the type of `(funcall g x)` is `float`.

So, I think we could say that Common Lisp is not a statically typed language as normally intended, but it *can* be optionally used as such, if one provides appropriate type information.

Comment: thank you. it is clear now :D !